# grok debugger regex usage

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'm testing [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), but I cannot get it to solve my problem.

**sample text:**

```
2014-06-17 04:37:30,317 c.e.A.MyActivity INFO main MyActivity.java 53 com.example.ApLogback.MyActivity$1 onClick logger track
```

How should I construct a grok regex/pattern string, so that it splits the previous sample text like in the following parts:

```
{
    timestamp:2014-06-17 04:37:30,317
    logger:c.e.A.MyActivity
    level:info
    caller_thread:main
    caller_method:MyActivity.java
    caller_line:53
    caller_class:com.example.ApLogback.MyActivity$1
    caller_method: onClick
    msg: caller track
}
```

My *current* regex is:

```
 (?<timestamp>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}) (?<logger>.*)
```

but it only splits the begining of the log string in parts. An example result of my current grok string is:

```
    {
      "timestamp": [
        [
          "2014-06-17 04:37:30,317"
        ]
      ],
      "logger": [
        [
          "c.e.A.MyActivity INFO main MyActivity.java 53 com.example.ApLogback.MyActivity$1 onClick logger"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Grok comes with many already-defined patterns that will cover most of your needs, check them out at: [Grok Debugger/patterns](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns)

As for a concrete answer to your question, here is a quick an dirty example that does what you need. It is just an example of how you can go about using already defined grok patterns to build your own pattern.

```
(?<timestamp>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}) (?:%{JAVACLASS:logger}) (?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}) (?:%{WORD:caller_thread}) (?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_file}) (?:%{NONNEGINT:caller_line}) (?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class}) (?:%{WORD:caller_method}) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:msg})
```